# Is Join syntax different in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-server-2012

I'm new to SQL Server and I'm using SQL Server Managment Studio 2012. I'm trying to do a very basic join, and I even copyed the syntax from an instruction video on PluralSight (using SQL Server 2008). Yet it does not excute.

This is the query:

```
USE [TestDB];

SELECT * FROM  Cities JOIN Persons
```

This is the message:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'Persons'.

The thing is when I use a "cross join" it seems to work fine with the expected results.
What am I doing wrong? And if I'm not doing anything wrong what could be the problem?

Comment: I don't think you copied the syntax very well, or perhaps the rest of the query was off-screen. :-)

Answer (score 4):

A join (other than a cross join) needs an on clause. Not knowing anything about your schema or how these two tables are related, perhaps you meant something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.Cities AS c 
INNER JOIN dbo.Persons AS p
ON c.CityID = p.CityID;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfect. I still could not reconcile the diffrence between the example on pluralsight and yours. But at least I got the answer :-)

Comment: I found my mistake, the example I saw was not using "AS", and I forgot to put the dot (.) in the right places in the  in the "on" clause. Its a newbie mistake :-) Your help was appreciated.

Comment: May want to mark @Aaron Bertrand's as the right answer :)